# 3D Printer keeps pausing during prints

Tags: troubleshooting, anycubic-chiron

I have used this 3D printer for over a year now and I just now started running into this problem. It is an Anycubic Chiron with no mods or anything custom added. It is placed in a cabinet my dad and I built to keep the heat in during the winter.

The problem started when the power went out. I came to the printer when the power was restored and it displayed the message, "The printer is sensing a lack a filament." So, I restarted it. It was no longer displaying that message, so I continued printing with it. Now, whenever I print anything longer than 10-20 minutes, it will randomly pause. Displaying the option to continue the print or stop the print. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify - the recent random pauses also say "sensing a lack of filament"  or are they just pauses ?

Comment: The first time I happened to see the "sensing a lack of filament" message, but I'm not sure whether it appears only for a short duration of time or if it lasts until the user presses ok. So, if I wanted to catch that again, I would have to wait anywhere from 30 minutes to 6 hours. So, I am now running it overnight with a camera to see if it displays the message, or if it just pauses. I hope this all makes sense and if there is anything you need me to clarify, please let me know.

Comment: drawing a line between a filament sensor and random pauses that are not present in the code leads through discrete input read fails... could be some issue with pullups?

Comment: What are Pullups?

Comment: I have confirmed that it is falsely sensing a lack of filament. it is happening more frequently now.